# ggplot2 "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type uneval."

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
Name    Passage growth
P1.X.1  1   42036
P1.X.1  2   42036
P1.X.1  3   42036
P1.X.2  1   42036
P1.X.2  2   42036
P1.X.2  3   42036
P1.X.3  1   42036
P1.X.3  2   42036
P1.X.3  3   42036
P1.X.4  1   42036
P1.X.4  2   42036
P1.X.4  3   42036
P1.X.1  1   42036
P1.X.1  2   42036
P1.X.1  3   42036
P1.X.2  1   42036
P1.X.2  2   42036
P1.X.2  3   42036
P1.X.3  1   42036
P1.X.3  2   42036
P1.X.3  3   42036
P1.X.4  1   42036
P1.X.4  2   42036
P1.X.4  3   42036

P.Plot <- qplot(aes(y = as.numeric(D.Subset$growth)), 
    data = D.Subset, x = as.numeric(D.Subset$Passage), 
    main = D.Subset$Name, geom = "line", facets = Name ~ .)
```

Error message:

```
"Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type uneval. Defaulting to continuous
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""uneval"" to a data.frame"
```

Added complete code:

My xlsx file:

```
UCPDate Date Sample Passage CellPlated Days CellCount Squares Volume VolPlated 
150901 150915 P1.X.1 1 25000 4 125 4 1,40 125 
150901 150916 P1.X.1 2 25000 4 124 4 1,40 124 
150901 150917 P1.X.1 3 25000 3 153 4 1,40 153 
150901 150915 P1.X.2 1 25000 4 176 4 1,40 176 
150901 150916 P1.X.2 2 25000 2 124 4 1,40 124 
150901 150917 P1.X.2 3 25000 3 135 4 1,40 135 
150901 150915 P1.X.3 1 25000 4 135 4 1,40 135 
150901 150916 P1.X.3 2 25000 2 142 4 1,40 142 
150901 150917 P1.X.3 3 25000 4 175 4 1,40 175 
150901 150915 P1.X.4 1 25000 5 157 4 1,40 157 
150901 150916 P1.X.4 2 25000 6 143 4 1,40 143 
150901 150917 P1.X.4 3 25000 4 143 4 1,40 143 
150903 150915 P1.X.1 1 25000 4 125 4 1,40 125 
150903 150916 P1.X.1 2 25000 4 124 4 1,40 124 
150903 150917 P1.X.1 3 25000 3 153 4 1,40 153 
150903 150915 P1.X.2 1 25000 4 176 4 1,40 176 
150903 150916 P1.X.2 2 25000 2 124 4 1,40 124 
150903 150917 P1.X.2 3 25000 3 135 4 1,40 135 
150903 150915 P1.X.3 1 25000 4 135 4 1,40 135 
150903 150916 P1.X.3 2 25000 2 142 4 1,40 142 
150903 150917 P1.X.3 3 25000 4 175 4 1,40 175 
150903 150915 P1.X.4 1 25000 5 157 4 1,40 157 
150903 150916 P1.X.4 2 25000 6 143 4 1,40 143 
150903 150917 P1.X.4 3 25000 4 143 4 1,40 143
```

My scrpit:

```
#----------------------dont change----------------------------------
if(require("xlsxjars") == FALSE){
  install.packages("xlsxjars")
  require("xlsxjars")
}

if(require("xlsx") == FALSE){
  install.packages("xlsx")
  require("xlsx")
}

if(require("ggplot2") == FALSE){
  install.packages("ggplot2")
  require("ggplot2")
}

D.Data <- read.xlsx(V.FileName, 
                sheetIndex = 1)

#-----------------------------------growth rate

L.CurrentCells <- ((D.Data["CellCount"] / D.Data["Squares"]) * 10000 * D.Data["Volume"])

D.Data$growth <- (L.CurrentCells / D.Data["CellPlated"]) ^ (1/D.Data["Days"])

#---------------------------------------------

L.Pieces <- unique(D.Data$UCPDate)

for(i in 1:length(L.Pieces)){

  D.Subset <- subset(D.Data, UCPDate == L.Pieces[i])  

  P.Plot1 <- ggplot(D.Subset, 
    aes(x=Passage,y=growth)) + 
    geom_line() +
    facet_grid(Sample~.)

    P.Plot1
}
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: The way you've been accessing variables in your dataframe causes new columns to keep the names of referenced columns --> your growth column didn't get created when I ran your code. Change it to `dfname$yourvariable`, for example `D.Data$growth <- (L.CurrentCells/D.Data$CellPlated) ^.....`

Comment: I have added the complete code, I hope you can help me

Comment: Did you read my comment? You need to change the way you're accessing columns of your dataframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the help for qplot, you can see that qplot doesn't take aes.

So you can construct the plot using ggplot:

```
P.Plot1 <- ggplot(D.Subset, 
                 aes(x=Passage,y=growth)) + 
                geom_line() +
                facet_grid(Name~.)
```

Or remove the aes from your call to qplot:

```
P.Plot2 <- qplot(data = D.Subset, 
                y = growth, 
                x = Passage, geom = "line", facets = Name ~ .)
```

Note that for both solutions you have already specified a dataframe. Therefore you can just use column names and you don't need `D.Subset$growth`. And it's probably better practice to convert your data to numeric (if that's necessary) before plotting.

Both result in:
[image]

Comment: I have tried both versions. I always get this Error: "Error: geom_line requires the following missing aesthetics: y" It was the reason, why i tried to include aes in qplot

Comment: I was able to make plots using both approaches and your data provided, so I'm not sure what's going on. Are you sure you spelled your column names correctly? And that both variables are numeric?

Comment: And y is specified in both of my options... What exactly did you do?